# Ubuntu shows as first priority boot option but keeps loading into windows, which is second priority

Tags: boot, dual-boot, process-priority

I have already installed Ubuntu 20.04 and made it first boot priority on my computer (asus 2019 zenbook) but my computer keeps jumping into the second boot option which is Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using Grub? How did you make Ubuntu it's first priority? How is Ubuntu installed? On a partition on the main hard disk? In a separate hard disk? These details are important to suggest an answer. Start by running `sudo fdisk -l`, then edit your question with the results.

Comment: I made ubuntu first priority by going into the bios. I installed ubuntu from a usb bootable drive. I made a partition from windows disk management and installed ubuntu on the new partition. btw thank you for your help

Comment: do you see grub when your OS boots up. It could be that the first entry in your grub is windows instead of linux. You can read the following to check and change the order : https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/

Comment: Maybe when you installed Ubuntu you didn't install grub properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the fast boot settings in BIOS, and the Power Settings `Turn on fast startup` in Windows and disable them. That fixed a similar issue for me.